# C# WebClient Upload Image to Server with Laravel

Tags: c#, php, .net, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to use a WebClient in C# to upload an image to my server using Laravel, and if it succeeds then insert data into a table and return a response to the C# WebClient with either failure or success.

I was thinking to create a Controller and create a function like...

```
class DropController extends BaseController() {
    public function getUpload($uid)
    {
        //here is where im not sure how to handle file upload WITHOUT a form 
    }
}
```

So I was hoping to be able to pass the image to the server by going to domain.com/upload/1
 with the webclient.upload() and One being the user id of course so that the image is assigned to that specific user.

Any ideas?
Thanks, Brandon

Comment: Sounds like a simple RESTful API to me is all you need

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'm currently following this tutorial on building a RESTful API for my application. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785

Or would you be able to suggest me something better to follow?

Comment: I always recommend laracasts.com - worth every cent